# AdMob ads takes time to load in android

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I have integrate admob native express ads in my android application but ads take some time to load.

please suggest how to decrease ads loading time on activity.

Thanks

Comment: please show how you are loading them ...

Comment: Before setContentView() i have used below code:- --

nativeAd = new NativeAd(PatternOnSecuredApp.this, "MY KEY");
        nativeAd.setAdListener(PatternOnSecuredApp.this);
        nativeAd.loadAd(NativeAd.MediaCacheFlag.ALL);

Comment: it usually takes some time to load as it has to be retrieved from the server, and its not a good idea to make the activity wait for it to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To load add speedy But How?

1. Initialize them in `onCreate` and after `setContentView()` view before doing anything else.
2. Dont load them in background thread.